# How to add Exchange price for product

Tags: magento-1.9

How to add Exchange price for product. If someone want to Exchange their product, we want to provide him different price.

How to solve this issue.

Is any extension for this?

Please help!

Comment: For the same or different product? It would probably easier to charge a fee instead.

Comment: to add Exchange price for the same product, a new attribute could be created and show the attribute as a block in product view page.

Comment: Thanks,
I have create attribute "Exchange price" and show it on front end. But it is not effect on main price when someone re-buy same product.
I want, when someone re-buy same product it will effect on main price.

Please help!

Comment: Can anyone help for this issue please.

Comment: @Neeraj do you mean that if someone once purchased that product he gets a reduction? So to check the previous orders for the users purchase history?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extra attribute type `price` via `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribues > New Attribute`.

Also set `Visible on product view page` on `Yes` so it's shown in the properties tab or add it to the templates product `view.phtml` (`app/design/frontend/[package]/[template]/templates/catalog/product/view.phtml`) by adding something like

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getData('exchange_price', true, false);?>
```

[image]

Now if you want to give